# Time delayed light/beeper beacon circuit

Tags: schematics, circuit-design

I need to build a timed beacon for locating and recovering the payload from a space balloon launch.  My Cub Scout Pack is launching a balloon to space. We have other recovery devices on board (radio, GPS, phone).  We want a backup audio-visual device that will have its own power source, start after a set time (3-4 hours) and continue to beep/light for at least an hour.  I saw a plan a while ago that used a simple programmable chip but I cannot find the specs. I'm looking for something simple to build from available parts.

Answer (score 1):

The strobe part could potentially be based on a Xenon flash tube, they are really bright. If you want to roll your own you could buy the tube and trigger transformers, there are numerous schematics on the web.
However you could use a basic module such as [this](http://xenonflashtubes.com/kits/12v-power-strobe_2-0.pdf) and simply set up a trigger circuit.
If you were to flash every 30 seconds or so on a small 3S LI-Ion battery pack you could probably get many hours of operation on a common 450 mAh RC battery such as [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01M2AS0XF) (though you are probably weight constrained).

I'm not sure the audible beep would get you any gain, it's hard to make something that can be heard at any distance.

Answer (score 0):

I would vote for a MCU. Power it via a crystal in low power mode. Or watchdog timer if you don't much about timing accuracy. Led strobe light would be great for this application.